# how to port an application that uses delegates to Java and the Android system

Tags: java, android, delegates

I have an application written in Delphi and ported to C# that makes extensive use of delegates (which allows me to add new modules easily). I think it would make a great Android phone app, but Java does not do delegates natively. I've seen a couple of examples of Java codes that tries to do delegates using reflection, but that does not seem efficient for a small device application.

Any suggestions about how I would go about porting my app without extensive re-architecture?

Comment: You might consider linking to some material describing "delegates", for those of us who do not recognize the term in this context.

Comment: Not sure this should be wiki.  Is a specific problem question.  People are less likely to answer a question in a wiki.  Wiki's are for discussion, not Q&A

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more details I can't suggest an exact porting method to fit your situation.

That being said, I would look at changing your delegates to event listeners.  Event listeners are quick to create, offer a common calling signature with the flexibility of being easily implemented with differeing functionality.  Also, they are very easy to move around dynamically.  Changing the target method is a simple matter of replacing the listener.  Calling the method is simply calling the event.

Interfaces are another option but are a lot heavier and less flexible on the mobile platform.

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses *EventListeners* instead of delegates. This is also called the observer pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern